# jQuery mask only allow certain combinations of digits

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set up the jQuery mask plugin to only accept certain data for the last two digits of a field.

What I want is this: YYYY[03],YYYY[06],YYYY[09],YYYY[12] to be marked valid and all other inputs to be marked invalid.

Examples:

- 201612 : Valid
- 201511 : Invalid
- 200403 : Valid
- 201102 : Invalid

So far, what I have is this:

```
$('#YearMonth').mask('0000XZ', {
    translation: {
      'X': {
        pattern: /[0-1]/, optional: true
      },
      'Z': {
        pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: true
      }
    }
});
```

Of course; this still doesn't work correctly. If there a way to use the jQuery mask plugin to do this? Or should I try another approach?

Thank you

Comment: What is the logic for determining what is valid or invalid ?

Comment: I probably don't have it in my code but the last two digits need to be one of (03,06,09,12(

Comment: @CrisK You should add that requirement to Question

Comment: @guest271314 he has it here: `What I want is this: YYYY[03],YYYY[06],YYYY[09],YYYY[12] to be marked valid and all other inputs to be marked invalid.`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain javascript, using regex

```
/\d{4}03|06|09|12/
```

```js
function validation(s) {
    var r = /\d{4}03|06|09|12/;
    return s.match(r) ? s + ": Valid" : s + ": Invalid";
}

//test
["201612", "201511", "200403", "201102"].forEach(e =>
    document.write(validation(e) + '<br>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pattern` attribute with `RegExp` `\d{4}(0[369]|12)`; add `required` attribute to prevent submission if `input` `value` is empty string. You can also use `oninput` event to clear `input` field if `value` does not match `pattern`. The form should not submit if `input` `value` does not match `RegExp` at `pattern` attribute.

```js
document.getElementById("YearMonth")
.oninput = function(e) {
  if (this.value.length === this.maxLength 
      && !new RegExp(this.pattern).test(this.value)) {
        alert("Invalid input\n" + this.title);
        this.value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="YearMonth">
    <input id="YearMonth" type="text" pattern="\d{4}(0[369]|12)" minlength="6" maxlength="6" title="Input: YYYY[03] OR YYYY[06] OR YYYY[09] OR YYYY[12]" placeholder="YYYY[03,06,09,12]" required />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```